# How to stop JAWS from reading "removed" content

Tags: sharepoint, screen, reader, jaws-screen-reader

I have an odd issue with the JAWS screen reader. I'm working an a page hosted on a SharePoint site and I'm using bootstrap's tabs. When I change tabs using JAWS, it reads the "removed" followed by the content of the previous tab, "removed" again, then the content of the tab you clicked. Oddly enough when I run the same page locally it doesn't do this.

In the example below (on SharePoint) if I am on the first tab, and click the second tab JAWS will announce "removed, content 1, removed, Content 2".

It doesn't do it below, but it does it on SharePoint. What can be different on SharePoint that would cause this?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">CONTENT 1  </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">CONTENT 2 </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">CONTENT 3 </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. The SharePoint site had the following Aria attributes:
aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"

"all" was what made it announce "removed" items. I changed it to "text" and now it announces the selected tab's content without announcing the previous tab's content.